# How to include multiple nonaggregated column when grouping by using Max function

Tags: mysql

I am still a learner in SQL Query, I already checked few  similier questions , but could not get my head around according to my problem.

Please find the out put in Sql Fiddle 
[SQL output](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7ec7da/2)

Basically I am trying to create an out put as such

```
id  sales_lead_id   comments    contact_type    time_spent  next_contact_date   contact_situation   employee_id date    created_at  updated_at

2651    1   rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr   0   3   2019-12-22  1   5   2019-12-21  2019-12-21T16:49:00Z    2019-12-22T18:05:37Z
2652    2   gggggggggggggg  0   17  2019-12-22  0   5   2019-12-19  2019-12-19T13:11:50Z    2019-12-22T18:15:59Z
```

I know how to get the row which has been edited most recetly by using Max(update_at) but 
I am unable to put other columns in the sql  (i.e id, comments,contact_type etc), I am not understanding how to pass this value  into main sql to get the full result as above.

any help will be really appreciated, stuck on this for long time.

Sql Full Table

```
select * from sales_lead_followup;
```

output

```
id  sales_lead_id   comments    contact_type    time_spent  next_contact_date   contact_situation   employee_id date    created_at  updated_at
1   1   dddddddddddddddddddddd  0   0   (null)  0   5   2019-05-18  2019-05-18T09:12:57Z    2019-05-18T09:12:57Z
2   2   dddddddddddd    0   0   (null)  0   5   2019-05-26  2019-05-26T06:32:56Z    2019-05-26T06:32:56Z
2651    1   rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr   0   3   2019-12-22  1   5   2019-12-21  2019-12-21T16:49:00Z    2019-12-22T18:05:37Z
2652    2   gggggggggggggg  0   17  2019-12-22  0   5   2019-12-19  2019-12-19T13:11:50Z    2019-12-22T18:15:59Z
1511    1   rrrrrr  0   6   2019-11-19  1   5   2019-11-17  2019-11-17T18:31:40Z    2019-11-19T18:30:07Z
1512    2   ggggggggggggg   0   2   2019-11-19  1   5   2019-11-17  2019-11-17T18:38:29Z    2019-11-19T18:38:23Z
```

SQL to get the  sales_lead_id which row has been added most recently

```
select sales_lead_id , max(updated_at) from sales_lead_followup  group by  sales_lead_id ;
```

output :-

```
   sales_lead_id    max(updated_at)
    1   2019-12-22T18:05:37Z
    2   2019-12-22T18:15:59Z
```

now some how i need to add additional columns in the above SQL to create bellow out put

```
id  sales_lead_id   comments    contact_type    time_spent  next_contact_date   contact_situation   employee_id date    created_at  updated_at

2651    1   rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr   0   3   2019-12-22  1   5   2019-12-21  2019-12-21T16:49:00Z    2019-12-22T18:05:37Z
2652    2   gggggggggggggg  0   17  2019-12-22  0   5   2019-12-19  2019-12-19T13:11:50Z    2019-12-22T18:15:59Z
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the output from your aggregate query inside an IN condition in your "main" query:

```
select * 
from sales_lead_followup 
WHERE (sales_lead_id, updated_at) IN 
    (
        select sales_lead_id , max(updated_at) 
        from sales_lead_followup  
        group by  sales_lead_id 
     );


+------+---------------+-------------------+--------------+------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------+------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|  id  | sales_lead_id |     comments      | contact_type | time_spent | next_contact_date | contact_situation | employee_id |    date    |      created_at      |      updated_at      |
+------+---------------+-------------------+--------------+------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------+------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| 2651 |             1 | rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr |            0 |          3 | 2019-12-22        |                 1 |           5 | 2019-12-21 | 2019-12-21T16:49:00Z | 2019-12-22T18:05:37Z |
| 2652 |             2 | gggggggggggggg    |            0 |         17 | 2019-12-22        |                 0 |           5 | 2019-12-19 | 2019-12-19T13:11:50Z | 2019-12-22T18:15:59Z |
+------+---------------+-------------------+--------------+------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------+------------+----------------------+----------------------+
```

[SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7ec7da/3)

That query may get out of hand though if that IN list grows in size (with just a few records it's pretty reasonable). Instead you may consider using a correlated subquery which will be much quicker, especially with an index on `sales_lead_id`:

```
select * 
from sales_lead_followup t1
WHERE updated_at =  
    (
        select max(updated_at) 
        from sales_lead_followup 
        WHERE sales_lead_id = t1.sales_lead_id
        group by  sales_lead_id 
     );
```

[SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7ec7da/5)